# Open link in new tab after X secs without pop up

Tags: javascript

I tried several things, but everytime Chrome (and others?) detect a pop up... is possible to bypass it ?

```
            window.open(
            '/test.php',
            '_blank'
            );
            }, 2000);
```

Comment: As the author of the site, no, it's not supposed to be possible. Typically, new tabs/windows can only be opened while handling certain user events, such as button/link clicks. The user can choose to allow the popup or disable popup blocking, but you have no control over whether they choose either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the code below?

```
//1000 = 1 second
setTimeout(function () {
    window.open('url here', '_blank);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @BaraqueObahamas, i've updated the answer to open in new tab

Comment: Too :-/ I think it's almost impossible to do

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open the window using javascript, then set a `setTimeout` for two seconds that would wait for a variable to be set.

The new window would have to set a variable in the parent window to, lets say true.

Then with the `setTimeout` runs, it checks whether the variable is true, and if not, then opens the link. If it is, then do nothing

```
var didItOpen = false;
window.open('page.html');
setTimeout(function () { if (!didItOpen) location.href = 'page.html'; }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thx. I tried, but it open directly the page, and the first page is redirected after 2 secs

Comment: @BaraqueObahamas it would be one way to open the page if the popup failed, but as the other comment mentions, there is no way to bypass the popup blocker of a browser using javascript in a simple way

Comment: Oh ok, I see! Thank you :)